# how to read .xlsm file line by line in perl

Tags: perl

This code reads the data from .xlsm file .this read data each cell by cell like cell(0,0) and like so on from this code i am not able to read data of whole line .I want to read .xlsm file line by line and also only of specified worksheet not all.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Spreadsheet::Reader::ExcelXML qw( :just_the_data);

my $workbook  = Spreadsheet::Reader::ExcelXML->new( file => 'filename.xlsm' 
);

if ( !$workbook->file_opened ) {
     die $workbook->error(), "\n";
 }

for my $worksheet ( $workbook->worksheets) {

    print "Reading worksheet named: " . $worksheet->get_name . "\n";

    while( 1 ){
            my $cell = $worksheet->get_next_value;

            print "Cell is: $cell\n";
            last if $cell eq 'EOF';
     }
 }
```

output:

```
    # SYNOPSIS Screen Output
    # 01: Row, Col    = (0, 0)
    # 02: Value       = Category
    # 03: Unformatted = Category
    # 04:
    # 05: Row, Col    = (0, 1)
    # 06: Value       = Total
    # 07: Unformatted = Total
    # 08:
    # 09: Row, Col    = (0, 2)
    # 10: Value       = Date
    # 11: Unformatted = Date
    # 12:
    # 13: Row, Col    = (1, 0)
    # 14: Value       = Red
    # 16: Unformatted = Red
    # 17:
    # 18: Row, Col    = (1, 1)
    # 19: Value       = 5
    # 20: Unformatted = 5
    # 21:
    # 22: Row, Col    = (1, 2)
    # 23: Value       = 2017-2-14 #(shows as 2/14/2017 in the sheet)
    # 24: Unformatted = 41318
    # 25:
    # More intermediate rows ...
    # 82:
    # 83: Row, Col    = (6, 2)
    # 84: Value       = 2016-2-6 #(shows as 2/6/2016 in the sheet)
    # 85: Unformatted = 40944
```

Comment: What does it mean to read a sheet "line by line" when a "line" contains potentially many cells of varying datatype?  What exactly do you want to receive for a "line"?

Comment: each row of data at once

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Do you assume it will be faster? Less code? More readable?

Comment: I found both of the things you want to do within five minutes of skimming the documentation. Since I did not know this module before, and I believe others also might not, I will write a short answer for the benefit of future readers. Next time, **please read the documentation yourself!**

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation, you can use the [`fetchrow_arrayref`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::Reader::ExcelXML::Worksheet#fetchrow_arrayref(-$row-)) and [`fetchrow_array`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::Reader::ExcelXML::Worksheet#fetchrow_array(-$row-)) methods on the [workbook level](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::Reader::ExcelXML::Worksheet) to get a full row.

> **`fetchrow_arrayref( $row )`**
>
> Definition: In an homage to DBI I included this function to return an
>   array ref of the cells or values in the requested $row. If no row is
>   requested this returns the 'next' row. In the array ref any empty cell
>   will show as 'undef'.
>
> Accepts: undef = next|$row = a row integer indicating the desired row
>   See the attribute "count_from_zero" in Spreadsheet::Reader::ExcelXML
>   to understand which row is returned for $row.
>
> Returns: an array ref of all possible column positions in that row
>   with data filled in per the attribute "group_return_type" in
>   Spreadsheet::Reader::ExcelXML.

Note that this module has its own definition of what a row is, and you can change that on import.

To load a specific worksheet, use the [`worksheet`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::Reader::ExcelXML#worksheet(-$name-)) method on the workbook object. You need to know the name of the worksheet beforehand, or you can get all of the names with [`get_sheet_names`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::Reader::ExcelXML#get_sheet_names).

> **`worksheet( $name )`**
>
> Definition: This method will return an object to read values in the
>   identified worksheet. If no value is passed to $name then the 'next'
>   worksheet in physical order is returned. 'next' will NOT wrap It also
>   only iterates through the 'worksheets' in the workbook (not the
>   'chartsheets').
>
> Accepts: the $name string representing the name of the worksheet
>   object you want to open. This name is the word visible on the tab when
>   opening the spreadsheet in Excel. (not the underlying zip member file
>   name - which can be different. It will not accept chart tab names.)
>
> Returns: a Worksheet object with the ability to read the worksheet of
>   that name. It returns undef and sets the error attribute if a
>   'chartsheet' is requested. Or in 'next' mode it returns undef if past
>   the last sheet.
>
> Example: using the implied 'next' worksheet;

Here is a quick, untested example that will open a specific worksheet, get the data line by line and dump out the results.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Spreadsheet::Reader::ExcelXML qw( :just_the_data);
use Data::Dumper;

my $workbook  = Spreadsheet::Reader::ExcelXML->new( 
    file => 'filename.xlsm' );

my $worksheet = $workbook->worksheet('foo');

while (my $row = $worksheet->fetchrow_array_ref) {
    print Dumper $row;
}
```

Comment: sir i am getting output like this:-$VAR1 = 1;
$VAR1 = 58;
$VAR1 = 52;
$VAR1 = 52;
$VAR1 = 52;
$VAR1 = 26;
$VAR1 = 1;
$VAR1 = 58;
$VAR1 = 52;
$VAR1 = 52;
$VAR1 = 52;
$VAR1 = 26;
$VAR1 = 1;
$VAR1 = 58;
$VAR1 = 52;
$VAR1 = 52;
$VAR1 = 52;
$VAR1 = 26;
$VAR1 = 1;
$VAR1 = 58;
$VAR1 = 52;
$VAR1 = 52;
$VAR1 = 52;
$VAR1 = 26;
$VAR1 = 1;
$VAR1 = 58;
$VAR1 = 52;
$VAR1 = 52;
$VAR1 = 52;
$VAR1 = 26;
$VAR1 = 1;
$VAR1 = 58;
$VAR1 = 52;
$VAR1 = 52;
$VAR1 = 52;
$VAR1 = 26;
$VAR1 = 1;
$VAR1 = 58;
$VAR1 = 52;
$VAR1 = 52;

Comment: i am using Active perl in windows

Comment: @Anand looks like you used `fetchrow_array`, not `fetchrow_array_ref`. That seems to be the number of elements in the array, because my example used a scalar `$row`. Without example input I cannot help you further. I read the documentation for you already. I cannot do your job for you unfortunately.

Comment: my data is in second sheet of .xlsm i.e 12-10-2017 xyz 10-2-1992 +91999999999 and so on in all the rows